# Disable future dates selection in FScalendar swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I am using https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar in  my project . MaximumSelectedDate is a read-only property .Then how can disable future dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround could be to edit `FSCalendar` method file. First make a bool variable, say `isAllowedToLimitFutureDates` and a string variable `maxValidFutureDateAsString` then change line 172 of [this link](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/FSCalendar/FSCalendar.m) to:

```
 if(!isAllowedToLimitFutureDates)
 {
     _maximumDate = [self.formatter dateFromString:@"2099-12-31"];
 }
 else
 {
     _maximumDate = maxValidFutureDateAsString; // say "2017-03-13"
 }
```

So when you want to limit the dates set `isAllowedToLimitFutureDates = true`.

Similar approach to line 1707.

In case you cannot edit file and used PODs, then you can customize this control and override them.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great!.. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 15):

You should be using the delegate method to address this

```
func maximumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
    return Date()
}
```

Comment: This should be marked answer, also if you want to disable previous days just make `minimumDate()` instead `maximumDate()`.

Comment: Thanks @Devraj . It is working fine . Yes this should be marked answer .

Comment: btw, this is a datasource method.

Answer (score 0):

@Devraj answer is correct, there are delegates for both *minimum* and *maximum* dates, all you need to do is implementing the proper one (the later one in your case) in the controller that's conforming to `FSCalendarDelegate` and that'll do the trick.

`func maximumDateForCalendar(calendar: FSCalendar) -> NSDate {
    return NSDate() // NSDate of your choosing here
}`

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 3

```
  fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter2: DateFormatter = {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
  return formatter }()       

  let today   = dateFormatter2.string(from: calendar.selectedDate!)
  let dateObj = dateFormatter2.date(from: today)

  if dateObj! > calendar.today! {
     // Your logic here
  }
```