# How to Disable Specific Date in FSCalendar Libary Swift

Tags: swift, fscalendar

i'm using [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) library to make calendar on my app, but how to disable specific date in calendar.

for example if i have data `2017-04-30` 30 April 2017 can't be selected.

Any idea how to make this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760793/disable-future-dates-selection-in-fscalendar-swift use this link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use FSCalendar delegate method,

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool
{
    if(date == your date)
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please implement **

> **-calendar:shouldSelectDate:**

and

> **-calendar:appearance:titleDefaultColorForDate:.**

The **DelegateAppearanceExample** and **StoryboardExample** might help you with the question. Hope this helps.