# how can we disable future dates and pass subtitle below date label in swift and how to use bridge header

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, xcode8

I have no idea how to use Objective-C in Swift file. I know how to create bridge header file but don't know how to to use it. https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar. I am using this pods. I want to disable future dates from today and pass a string to subtitle label in calendar. I want to implement this in Swift. I saw a Swift example on github.com but not worked Thanks is advance!

I've also tried this
[Disable future dates selection in FScalendar swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760793/disable-future-dates-selection-in-fscalendar-swift)

```
if(!isAllowedToLimitFutureDates) 
{
    _maximumDate = [self.formatter dateFromString:@"2099-12-31"];
}
else
{
    _maximumDate = maxValidFutureDateAsString; // say "2017-03-13"
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood your case: you are using `FSCalendar` and you want to disable the highlight of the dates starting from tomorrow, correct?

Comment: yes that is correct @AhmadF and also want to pass a some string below date label that is in sub title.

Comment: These are multiple questions, so the viewer might getting confused about it. I can answer the disabling one :) You might want to separate them later...

Comment: sure that will work @AhmadF thanks

Answer (score 2):

In [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar), you could set the maximum date to be selected by conforming to `FSCalendarDataSource` thus implementing:

```
maximumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date
```

which tells the calendar view what is the maximum date that allowed to be highlighted. For instance:

Make sure that you are conforming to the delegate:

```
// conform to FSCalendarDelegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, FSCalendarDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // assign the delegate
        calendar.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

and then add into your view controller:

```
func maximumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
    return Date()
}
```

which means the maximum date is today.

**Output:**

[image]

As you can see, you would be able to select any previous date but not more than today, date starting from tomorrow are grayed (dimmed and unselectable).

Comment: thank you but I get this error now Cannot load module 'fscalendar' as 'FSCalendar' not able to add delegate also

Comment: @Begineers have you import it in the .swift file (`import FSCalendar`)?

Comment: yes I import it then I got errro Cannot load module 'fscalendar' as 'FSCalendar'

Comment: @Begineers it could be related to the bridging header. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: I checked it can you please email me the your project created now at iosbeginners09@gmail.com I can verify it

Comment: @Begineers there is something better than send it to your email, open terminal and run `pod try 'FSCalendar'` :) That's what I did, then I edited it.

Comment: It is saying Updating spec repositories. one more thing have you imported anything in header file created is yes please let me know?

Comment: @Begineers No, I didn't. After finishing "Updating spec repositories" it should give you 4 options to select your desired case...

Comment: Tried but same error "Cannot load module 'fscalendar' as 'FSCalendar" when I import FSCalendar

Comment: I got it but future date is not disabled I took uiview reference in file as calendar.   class ViewController: UIViewController, FSCalendarDelegate{    
    @IBOutlet weak var calendar: FSCalendar! 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        calendar.delegate = self 
    }
    
    func maximumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
        return Date()
    } } what is calendar in your code is it uiview reference?

Comment: @Begineers what's the version of Swift you are using?

Comment: @DilipTiwari you could get it by implementing `didSelectDate` method from `FSCalendarDelegate`, it contains the selected date (as `Date`).

Comment: @DilipTiwari I'd assume that it should work... Make sure that you are typing the correct signature for it (it could be it needs "_" before parameter names or something like this).

Comment: func maximumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
        return Date()
    }

and set         calendar.delegate = self
in viewdidload

its not working

Comment: @DilipTiwari `maximumDate` is for setting the maximum date for the calendar, `didSelectDate` is for selecting the date. What are aiming to achieve?!

Comment: bro i want to disable future dates only that's why i tried this

Comment: and i have added two buttons above calendar when i click on Start date i have to select date and when i click on End date i have to select date then it will select all dates automatically between start and end date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191076/discussion-between-ahmad-f-and-dilip-tiwari).